# Use Selectize.js on dynamically add more select element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2, selectize.js

I have a form with a Select input using selectize.js where users can add more input elements.

But when a new select element was created the select option didn't show. Only the First select element shows the option.

First Select Element working properly
[image: First Select Element working]

But the second Element didn't show the select option
[image: Second element not working]

here is my HTML:

```
<div id="list-item">
    <div class="form-row item">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="position-relative form-group">
                <select name="item-name[]" id="item-name" class="item-name form-control" required>
                    <option value="" selected>Ketikkan nama barang</option>
                    <option value="1">Pulpen (Pcs)</option>
                    <option value="2">Spidol (Pcs)</option>
                    <option value="3">Air Mineral Gelas (Dos)</option>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Pilih minimal 1 Barang
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input name="qty[]" id="qty" value="0" min="1" type="number" class="qty form-control" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Masukkan Jumlah Barang
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="position-relative form-group">
    <button type="button" id="btn-add-item" class="btn btn-primary mr-3">Add More</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-delete-item" class="btn btn-transition btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="mt-2 btn btn-success btn-block">Save</button>
```

Here is My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // $('.item-name').select2();
    $('.item-name').selectize({
        create: false
    });
});

const btnAddItem = document.getElementById('btn-add-item');
const btnDeleteItem = document.getElementById('btn-delete-item');
const moreItemElement = document.getElementsByClassName('item')[0];

btnAddItem.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const clone = moreItemElement.cloneNode(true);
    let newItem = document.getElementById('list-item').appendChild(clone);
    let itemSelect = newItem.getElementsByClassName(".item-name").value = '';
    newItem.getElementsByClassName(".qty").value = 0
})

btnDeleteItem.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let listItem = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
    let lastItem = listItem[listItem.length - 1];
    lastItem.parentNode.removeChild(lastItem);
})
```

Comment: Please edit your question and use the snippet tool `<>` to create a working example of your problem. Also why mix javascript and jquery?

Comment: I believe the reason why your second dropdown does not work is because you haven't run `$('.item-name').selectize(` for the new element.